# force close edit text above map view in android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-relativelayout, android-edittext

I want to add edit text above the mapview in android
so I created this layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/base">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:id="@+id/zoomtext"
    >
</EditText>

<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="myAPIkey"
    android:layout_below="@+id/zoomtext"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

here's my java code

```
package zoom.map;

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class ZoomapActivity extends MapActivity {
EditText zoombtn;
int angkazoom;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    zoombtn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.zoomtext);
    angkazoom = mapView.getZoomLevel();
    zoombtn.setText(angkazoom);
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
}
```

and this is my error log cat

```
04-18 13:08:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(309): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-18 13:08:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(309): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{zoom.map/zoom.map.ZoomapActivity}:    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x3
04-18 13:08:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
04-18 13:08:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-18 13:08:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-18 13:08:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-18 13:08:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-18 13:08:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-18 13:08:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-18 13:08:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-18 13:08:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-18 13:08:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-18 13:08:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-18 13:08:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-18 13:08:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(309): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x3
04-18 13:08:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:201)
04-18 13:08:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2817)
04-18 13:08:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at zoom.map.ZoomapActivity.onCreate(ZoomapActivity.java:21)
04-18 13:08:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-18 13:08:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
04-18 13:08:37.230: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  ... 11 more
```

I can't figure out what's wrong..
No problem with the layout and I have no error in the java
I've searched through stackoverflow and haven't found the answer yet..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
angkazoom = mapView.getZoomLevel();
```

Is retrieving an integer value.

When calling

```
zoombtn.setText(angkazoom);
```

android assumes you are trying to set your text to a String resource ID (an int).. This ID "should" map to a string value.. When it searches for that ID it fails since it doesn't exist and causes your crash.

If what you want to show is just the zoom level use

```
zoombtn.setText(angkazoom + "");
```

to allow your text to show the zoom level in string representation

Comment: thx for your answer, it really helps (:
but anyway I've choosen the .setText(int resid) so I thought that I don't have to change the type to string